# Dynamic HTTP listener with JS

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, http

I am developing a winform application and I would like to use HTTP listener implementation (wiht CSS and JS) to dynamically inform the user about the status of the winform app. By dynamic I mean that the the content of the webpage would update without the need of reloading the webpage itself (creating a new request). My thought was to use javascript which would e.g. every second check a state of some c# variable but I cannot figure out/google how to do it.

Would something like this be even possible? I am open to completely new solutions like adding a new web project (asp under .net core etc.) that would be compiled as dll and run from the winform app but I would like to avoid deploying my application with standalone server.

Example of the listener below:

```
// This example requires the System and System.Net namespaces.
public static void SimpleListenerExample(string[] prefixes)
{
    if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Windows XP SP2 or Server 2003 is required to use the HttpListener class.");
        return;
    }
    // URI prefixes are required,
    // for example "http://contoso.com:8080/index/".
    if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
      throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

    // Create a listener.
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    // Add the prefixes.
    foreach (string s in prefixes)
    {
        listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
    }
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    // Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request.
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    // Obtain a response object.
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
    // Construct a response.
    string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Hello world!</BODY></HTML>";
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
    // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
    output.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
    // You must close the output stream.
    output.Close();
    listener.Stop();
}
```

Comment: This could be driven from the front-end via some kind of AJAX call to check if there's a change, or you could alternatively use a WebSocket and then trigger the change from the server.  There's a variety of other ways of accomplishing it, these are just a couple of suggestions

Comment: I could not figure out how to call a c# function from ajax (more precisely from winforms; it is possible to call it from .aspx files with the use of ASP .NET). A functional fix for me was to add page reloading every second to the head meta in HTML. Not the best solution though, so I will keep it as a plan B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I used ajax as suggested in the comments. Basically my javascript makes a query (e.g get_content) every second with the use of setInterval() function and I have defined a response in my c# code.